# Code refactoring tools for C, usable on GNU/Linux? FOSS preferable

Tags: c, linux, refactoring, gnu

Variations of this question have been asked, but not specific to GNU/Linux and C.  I use Komodo Edit as my usual Editor, but I'd actually prefer something that can be used from CLI.
I don't need C++ support; it's fine if the tool can only handle plain C.

I really appreciate any direction, as I was unable to find anything.
I hope I'm not forced to 'roll' something myself.

NOTE: Please refrain from mention `vim`; I know it exists and what its capabilities are.  I purposefully choose to avoid `vim`, which is why I use Komodo (or nano on the servers).

Comment: Are you opposed to emacs as well?

Comment: Yes, I would choose `vim` over `emacs`... but hate them both with a passion.  I'm the only sysadmin at work that says "neither", when asked which I prefer.  I use `nano` on the servers, and Komodo Edit on my local machine. It's been cathartic, never touching `vim` again.

Comment: Code refactoring for C? Coccinelle: http://coccinelle.lip6.fr/

Comment: How do "text editors" qualify as "C refactoring" tools?

Comment: @Ira Baxter: They don't, just seems like some people think they might.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that a pure console refactoring tool would be nice to use. 
I use Eclipse CDT on linux to write and refactor C-Code. 
 There exists also Xrefactory for Emacs http://www.xref.sk/xrefactory/main.html

if a non console refactoring tool is o.k for you as well.

Comment: ... I hate Eclipse, I'm a Komodo guy.   With that said... Your the only one who actually attempted to answer my question.  So while they might not be a great fit for me, they run do on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

C-xrefactory was an open source version of [xrefactory](http://www.xrefactory.com), covering C and Java, made available on [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/c-xref/) by Marián Vittek under GPLv2.

For those interested, there's an actively maintained c-xrefactory fork on GitHub:

https://github.com/thoni56/c-xrefactory

The goal of the GitHub fork is to refactor c-xrefactory itself, add a test suite, and try to document the original source code (which is rather obscure). Maybe, in the future, also convert it into an LSP C language server and refactoring tool.

C-xrefactory works on Emacs; setup scripts and instructions can be found at the repository. Windows users can run it via WSL/WSL2.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider coding a GCC plugin or a [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension (MELT is a domain specific language to extend GCC) for your needs.

However, such approach would take you some time, because you'll need to understand some of GCC internals.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows only, and not FOSS but you said "any direction..."

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit"](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) with its [C Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CFrontEnd.html) can apply transformations to C source code.    DMS can be configured to carry out custom, complex *reliable* transformations, although the configuration isn't as easy as typing just a command like "refactor frazzle by doobaz".

One of the principal stumbling blocks is still the preprocessor.  DMS can transform code that has preprocessor directives in typical places (around statements, expressions, if/for/while loop heads, declarations, etc.)  but other "unstructured conditionals" give it trouble.   You can run DMS by expanding the preprocessor directives out of existence, or more imporantly, expanding out the ones that give it trouble, but mostly people don't like this because they prefer to keep thier preprocessor directives.   So it isn't perfect.

[Another answer suggested Concinelle, which looks pretty good from my point of view.  As far as I know, it doesn't handle preprocessor directives at all; I could be wrong and it might handle some cases as DMS does, but I'm sure it can't handle all the cases].

You don't want to consider rolling your own.  Building a transformation/refactoring tool is much harder than you might guess having never tried it. You need full, accurate parsers for the (C) dialect of interest and just that is pretty hard to get right.  You need a preprocessor, symbol tables, flow analysis, transformation, code regeneration machinery, ...  this stuff takes years of effort to build and get right.  Trust me, been there, done that.

Comment: It's pretty obvious from the context of '... any direction...', that I was referring to any direction towards my stated requirements.  The question was never "help me find *ANY* refactoring tool".  In addition ... when I said 'roll my own', I was talking about 'rolling' my own solution.  Taking care of the problem, possibly by creating some shell scripts, never would I consider creating an entire refactoring project.  I'm just not at that level, and I've known this for a very long time.

Comment: @TechZilla:  When you say "any direction", you cast a very wide net.  When I hear somebody say "roll" (their own), I interpret that as "willing to build something" with significant effort; I responded to that interpretation.  I assume other folks do, too.  [FWIW, DMS seems to run fine under Wine on Linux, but most users of Linux seem to detest that solution.]